# code run before every actions in a module ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

I want to write some code to run before every actions in my module.  I have tried hooking onto `onBootstrap()` but the code run on the other modules too.

Any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to do this.

One way is to create a serice and call it in every controllers dispatch method

```
Use onDispatch method in controller. 


    class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {


        /**
         * 
         * @param \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e
         * @return type
         */
        public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e) {

            //Call your service here

            return parent::onDispatch($e);
        }

        public function indexAction() {
            return new ViewModel();
        }

    }
```

don't forget to include following library on top of your code

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
```

Second method is to do this via Module.php using event on dispatch

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module {

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {        
        $sharedEvents = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', array($this, 'addViewVariables'), 201);
    }

    public function addViewVariables(Event $e) {
        //your code goes here
    }

    // rest of the Module methods goes here...
    //...
    //...
}
```

[How to create simple service using ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562538/zf2-creation-of-simple-service-and-access-it-through-viewhelper)

[reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406507/modulemanager-geteventmanager-getsharedmanager-attach-is-not-working-in)

[reference3](http://lab.empirio.no/how-to-attach-mvc-events-in-zf2.html)

Comment: Just as a comment, it would be great if you can shorten your code examples. It is only little helpful to get a bunch of code posted and to figure out everything on your own. Please explain what you're doing (i know it, but questionaire might not)

Comment: Thanks Sam for reminding me that only bother to answer a question if you have enough time to answer it precisely. otherwise don't waste your time for quick answer. I will keep this in mind and only answer a question if i would have enough time to answer thoroughly.

Comment: tks so much for your answer. I can do it now.

Comment: For clarity this answer worked, I agree it may help to explain more but it does solve the problem.